# OpenWRT Chaos Calmer 15.05 DNS forwarding, custom DNS Server, DHCP option - nothing works

Tags: dns, dhcp, openwrt, dnsmasq

Okay, so essentially I'm trying to only forward one very specific address over one of those geo unblock dns proxy services. Namely Pandora.com. Don't judge, I like their raido stations better than what Spotify provides.

First thing I tried: DNS Forwarding -> /pandora.com/Unblock-DNS-IP

Not working.

Second thing: Assign the WAN interface a custom DNS server (out of desperation, I'm aware that all DNS requests would thus go through that server)

Not working.

Third thing: Go to DHCP options, assign custom DNS there.

6,Unblock-DNS-IP1,Unblock-DNS-IP2

Not working either. I tried both doing either thing on it's own and applying all three at the same time. Now I'm slowly running out of options, it seems whatever I do, my router refuses to use custom DNS servers. I tried the DNS servers seperately on my phone and desktop pc, they're working fine, so it has to be a problem on my end.

Anyone ever encountered anything similar or any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching, this worked for me on openwrt, with separate wifi and lan interfaces, not bridged:

```
iptables -I PREROUTING -t nat -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination dnsaddr
iptables -I PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination dnsaddr
```

Place in custom rules